# Why the richTextbox control is not location in the middle of the form1?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void btnSettingsFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtx1 = new RichTextBox();
    rtx1.Size = new Size(250,250);
    rtx1.BackColor = Color.Black;
    rtx1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    this.Controls.Add(rtx1);
    rtx1.BringToFront();
    rtx1.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2);
    rtx1.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(settingsFile));
}
```

first I tried this.Width / 2 and this.Height /  2 but it put it on the right bottom then I tried with the ClientSize but this put it a bit to the bottom not in the center of form1.

I want the richTextBox to be in the center of form1.

[image: not in the center of form1]

Comment: Is the top left corner of the RTF box in the middle of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control's `.Location` property marks its top left corner, not its center. Therefore the top left corner of the control **IS** centered on the form, and this matches what we can see in the image.

To fix it, you need to subtract back 1/2 of the length and width of the control.

```
rtx1.Location = new Point( (this.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (rtx1.Width / 2), (this.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (rtx1.Height / 2) );
```